# drop rows based on multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Having a data set as below:

| Product | Price | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 5 |
| A | 6 | Nan |
| A | 7 | Nan |
| B | 8 | Nan |
| B | 8 | Nan |
| B | 8 | 4 |
| A | 5 | 5 |
| A | 5 | 2 |
| A | 5 | 1 |
| A | 4 | 3 |
| B | 4 | 6 |
| B | 3 | 7 |

I need to drop rows if product is B , and price is 8. I tried the below code:

```
df.drop(df[(df['Product'] == 'B') & df['Price'] == 8].index,axis=0,inplace = True)
```

There is no error message. But the rows are not removed.

Comment: Use `df[(df['Product'] != 'B') | (df['Price'] != 8)]`

Comment: It drops all the rows related to B. I need to specifically drop the rows where product name is B and price is 8.

Comment: Instead your code use `df[(df['Product'] != 'B') | (df['Price'] != 8)]`

Comment: its working. Why we use |(or) here. I thought its and(&)?

Comment: because inverting logic - need for select rows `==` with and(`&`) and inverting is `!=` with or (`|`)